# How to draw an image over another?

Tags: java, 2d-games

So I am working on a project for a class. And I've been struggling with this issue for a while now. The code below is a start screen, and when the enter key is pressed (when `atTitle` turns to false) I would like it to draw the next image. The problem with that is I can not think of a way for it to draw the next image when it turns to false. I've tried using ifs and whiles.  Mainly the problem is that you obviously put another `public void paintComponent` in an if statement.  And I can't carry the `Graphics g` variable to the `KeyPressed` method. 
I'm stuck.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    g2.setTransform(at);
    if (atTitle == true) {
        g.drawImage(titlescreen, 0, 0, this);
        if (start_visible == true) {
            g.drawImage(start_symbol, -70, 30, this);
            jf.addKeyListener(this);
        }
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (atTitle == true) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            atTitle = false;
            System.out.println("It Works.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than pursuing this route you need to take a look at scene graphs and understand how they function. It will take some up front time investment, but in the long run will be entirely worth it if you pursuing making an actual game. (Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm)

Comment: It seems interesting and I probably will have a look at it, since it looks like it would be a good thing to know. 
But at the moment I am on a time constraint.

Comment: Even if you don't use the javafx scene graph you still need to build a graph of objects that need to be rendered inside your `paintComponent` method; then the `keyPressed` event can modify that graph and invoke a method that signals the canvas to repaint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPanel you should:

```
panel.setFocusable(true);
panel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

[Referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498147/addkeylistener-doesnt-work-for-jpanel)

Also you can call panel.revalidate() and/or panel.repaint() in the key press.

Maybe try to stay away from JPanel and Swing altogether (not suited for gaming, but for forms) and just use the graphics2D functionality with a Window, Frame and Canvas, as suggested in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `repaint` and wait system calls to `paint` function. you should not keep `graphic` object and use it in a function is not child function of `paint`

as a simple canvas component, you can use this one

```
class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
        private Thread thread;
        public Game(){
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // paint your game
        }
        public void stop(){
            thread = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (thread == Thread.currentThread()){
                long ti = System.currentTimeMillis();
                repaint();
                long ti2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long waitTime = 60 - (ti2-ti);
                if (waitTime > 0){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                    } catch (Exception e){

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```