# KeyListener on jTextField is not working

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jtextfield, keylistener

I added event to my jTextField

```
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextField1KeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
```

and here is second part of my code (responsible for handling keyboard buttons):

```
 private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_1:
                    print(one);
                    System.out.println("1");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_2:
                    print(two);
                    System.out.println("2");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_3:
                    print(three);
                    System.out.println("3");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_4:
                    print(four);
                    System.out.println("4");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_5:
                    print(five);
                    System.out.println("5");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_6:
                    print(six);
                    System.out.println("6");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_7:
                    print(seven);
                    System.out.println("7");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_8:
                    print(eight);
                    System.out.println("8");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_9:
                    print(nine);
                    System.out.println("9");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_0:
                    print(zero);
                    System.out.println("0");
                    break;
            }
    }
```

But it's not working. When I any button - nothing is happening.

Comment: Try using a default statement to see if the switch statement is being run.

Comment: Please provide more context of what this textField is within and what you're doing with it. Particularly, does it have focus?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and see what is the actual value of evt.getKeyCode()?

Comment: I strongly urge you to change your tack enterly. You should not use a KeyListener inside of a JTextField as that messes up the JTextField's functioning. Use a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter or one of the other much better options. Since you don't appear to be restricting input, go with the DocumentListener attached to the JTextField's Document via `addDcoumentListener(...)`.

Comment: See what the value of the keycode is and print it. Make sure it's being run.

Comment: @Saposhiente this textField is within jFrame. When I run my program it seems to have focus http://imgur.com/VARjpVh

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I tried to make external class KeyHandler which would trigger the same method as my buttons are triggering but when I write instance of my main class CalculatorGUI calc = new CalculatorGUI(); in my KeyHandler class and when I make instance of KeyHandler in main class KeyHandler keyboard = new KeyHandler(); I get stackOverflow error [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603527/i-get-stackoverflow-error-when-i-create-new-instance-in-external-class)

Comment: I second, third and fourth Hovercrafts comments, don't use a KeyListener for this job, it's inappropriate and doesn't take into account what would happen if the user pasted text into the field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly urge you to change your tack enterly. You should not use a KeyListener inside of a JTextField as that messes up the JTextField's functioning. Use a DocumentListener or DocumentFilter or one of the other much better options. Since you don't appear to be restricting input, go with the DocumentListener attached to the JTextField's Document via addDcoumentListener(...).

i.e,

```
jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

        void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

        void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

        void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

    }

});
```

Edit: if you are wanting to capture number key presses for a calculator, then don't use this either. Rather use Key Bindings.

Comment: Ok, I will look into DocumentListener and DocumentFilter but firstly I will try to do something with key bindings.

Comment: @MichałGwóźdź: please check out the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use a DocumentListener or a ChangeListener also FocusListener could be an option keyListener does do the job but it has some focus issues when using it if you want to avoid the focus issues use KeyBindings or you can try to explicitly call the grabFocus() method for the specific component, its so keyListener when registered with a component needs that component to be in focus.

Comment: Key bindings might be too restrictive and would be unadvisable for the same reasons as `KeyListener` would be for a text component.  The best option, as suggested by HovercraftFullOfEels already, is the `DocumentListener`, as this will notify you when the document is changed either by the user typing something, pasting something to the field been programmatically modified...

Comment: Then well change listener might do the job well enough for all sorts of changes

Comment: But `JTextField` doesn't have `ChangeListener` support, the `DocumentListener` IS the best choice...

Comment: Yeah my bad changelistener isn't compatible your'e right but i was thinking key bindings would just do the job well enough but i also feel documentlistener would be better though it requires a little more practice

Comment: Key bindings would require you to bind EVERY possible combination key strokes...that's a a lot of work...