# KeyPressed isnt working

Tags: java, keyevent

```
 class Card31 extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener {
     public Card31() {
         addKeyListener(this);
         addMouseListener(this);
         x1 = 700;

     }

     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

     }

     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)

     {

     }

     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)

     {

         key = e.getKeyCode();
         if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
             x1 += 10;
         else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
             x1 -= 10;
         repaint();
     }
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         requestFocus();
     }

     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

     }
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

     }
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         court2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("court2.jpg");
         bhoop = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bhoop2.png");
         balla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balla.png");
         ballc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballc.png");
         balld = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balld.png");
         balle = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balle.png");
         ballf = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballf.png");
         balli = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balli.png");
         balll = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balll.png");
         balln = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balln.png");
         ballo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballo.png");
         ballr = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballr.png");
         balls = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("balls.png");
         ballt = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballt.png");
         ballu = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ballu.png");
         bally = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bally.png");
         g.drawImage(court2, 0, 0, 1600, 1000, this);
         g.drawImage(ballo, 130, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(ballc, 280, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(balln, 430, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(balld, 580, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(balle, 730, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(ballc, 880, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(balle, 1030, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(ballu, 1180, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawImage(bally, 1330, 100, 110, 110, this);
         g.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 20);
         Font plainfont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);
         g.setFont(plainfont);
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g.drawString("Score: " + score1, 30, 30);
         g.fillRect(700, 800, 200, 20);
         g.drawImage(bhoop, x1, 500, 150, 150, this);

         g.drawString(msg1, 200, 200);
         System.out.println("x1" + x1);
     }
 }
```

Above I attached part of the code, a nested class. X1 is a global variable and is initialized in the constructor. The KeyPressed, which is used for moving the Iamge bhoop, is not working. I have checked all the code to make it right but the Image is not moving no matter what. Please help me solve this. I would really appreciate your help<3.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners/22741216).

Comment: As has been answered in many similar questions -- don't use KeyListeners for this but instead use Key Bindings. Otherwise your forced to use the kludge of making your JPanel retain the focus, not good. Also, don't read all those images in the paintComponent method as this will slow your GUI's responsiveness to a crawl. Instead read the images in once, say in a constructor, and store the images or ImageIcons in fields.

Answer (score 2):

The Component which has a registered `KeyListener` must have `focus` for the `KeyListener` to fire. Call `requestFocus` on the Component to request that the component has focus, or better yet use [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: [addKeyListener() doesn't work for JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498147/addkeylistener-doesnt-work-for-jpanel)

your panel needs to be focusable:

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Comment: A terrible terrible kludge. Now you are forced to prevent all other components from gaining the focus. The better answer is to use Key Bindings.