# How Do I Implement a Key Listener On My Main Class?

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how to make this onKeyListener for a while and I have been seriously confused on how to do it. Do I need to implement it separately in it's own class? Or can I implement it into my main method like I want?

Class Creation
    public class PlayMat extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

Code From My Main Method:

```
private static JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Cake");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    mainFrame.add(new PlayMat());
    mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);     
    mainFrame.addKeyListener((KeyListener) mainFrame.getAccessibleContext());
}
```

Comment: Why from the main method ? Why not from the load event ?  Also if you are from inside the class, you can just pass `this` as a listener, because you declared it `public class PlayMat extends JPanel implements KeyListener {`

Comment: This has some clues as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498147/addkeylistener-doesnt-work-for-jpanel